# How can I convert an XML without attributes to C# properties?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having trouble converting my XML to a C# object.

My XML looks like this:

```
<metadata>
<item name="Date" type="xs:date"/>
<item name="Hour" type="xs:time"/>
<item name="Group" type="xs:string" length="12"/>
<item name="Status" type="xs:string" length="18"/>
</metadata>
<data>
<row>
<value>2020-05-08</value>
<value>14:00:01</value>
<value>A</value>
<value>Active</value>
</row>
<row>
<value>2020-05-08</value>
<value>14:00:01</value>
<value>B</value>
<value>Inactive</value>
</row>
</data>
</metadata>
```

I want to map the XML to a c# object that looks like this

```
public class GroupDto

    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Hour { get; set; }
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

(the date and hour can be a string, no problem)
 I'm using JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc), but it's giving me this result:

```
   "data": {
      "row": [
         {
            "value": [
               "2020-05-08",
               "14:00:01",
               "A",
               "Active"
            ]
         },
....
```

I like to map the "values" to the corresponding properties of the C# object.
Is there a propper way to achieve this with an XML in this weird format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't trust the order of the properties, you can try something like this:

```
var metadata = doc.Root.Element("metadata");

var mapper = metadata.Elements("item")
    .Select((i, c) => new { Property = i.Attribute("name").Value, Index = c })
    .ToDictionary(i => i.Property, i => i.Index);

var rows = doc.Root.Element("data").Elements("row").Select(r => new GroupDto
{
    Date = r.Elements("value").ElementAt(mapper[nameof(GroupDto.Date)]).Value,
    Hour = r.Elements("value").ElementAt(mapper[nameof(GroupDto.Hour)]).Value,
    Group = r.Elements("value").ElementAt(mapper[nameof(GroupDto.Group)]).Value,
    Status = r.Elements("value").ElementAt(mapper[nameof(GroupDto.Status)]).Value,
}).ToList();
```

It might not be the most optimal solution, but it gives you what you want in a not-so-complex way.

On top of that, if your properties in your xml wouldn't match the properties of your DTO object, you can always introduce an additional mapping layer. For example:

```
var metaMapper = metadata.Elements(ns + "item")
    .Select((i, c) => new { Property = i.Attribute("name").Value, Index = c })
    .ToDictionary(i => i.Property, i => i.Index);

var metaPropertyMapper = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {  nameof(GroupDto.Date),  "DateInXML" },
    {  nameof(GroupDto.Hour),  "HourInXML" },
    {  nameof(GroupDto.Group), "GroupInXML" },
    {  nameof(GroupDto.Status), "StatusInXML" },
};

var rows = doc.Root.Element(ns + "data").Elements(ns + "row").Select(r => new GroupDto
{
    Date = r.Elements(ns + "value").ElementAt(metaMapper[metaPropertyMapper[nameof(GroupDto.Date)]]).Value,
    Hour = r.Elements(ns + "value").ElementAt(metaMapper[metaPropertyMapper[nameof(GroupDto.Hour)]]).Value,
    Group = r.Elements(ns + "value").ElementAt(metaMapper[metaPropertyMapper[nameof(GroupDto.Group)]]).Value,
    Status = r.Elements(ns + "value").ElementAt(metaMapper[metaPropertyMapper[nameof(GroupDto.Status)]]).Value,
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make some rules for the deserialization, if there is no way to differenciate values from values.

Assuming that you simply don't trust the properties to be in the right order, you can use the following group of rules :

- Date and Hour are both parsable into `DateTime`
- Hour contains `':'` and Date do not.
- either Group is only letter or Status match a list of known Status

```
foreach(var row in data.Row){
    var temp = new GroupDto();
    foreach(var val in row.Value){

        if( DateTime.TryParse(val, out DateTime date) )
        {
            if(val.Contains(':')) //it should be a time
            {
                temp.Hour = date.ToShortTimeString(); //or keep the datetime format
            }
            else
            {
                temp.Hour = date.ToShortDateString();
            }           
        }

        //either based status on a list of know status
        else if(knowStatus.Contains(val))
        {
            temp.Status = val;
        }       
        //or base Group detection on string lenght and default the remaining possibility to status
        else if(val.lenght>1)
        {       
            temp.Status = val;
        }

        else {      
            temp.Group  = val;
        }
    }
    // return temp/ yeild return temp/ Add it to a list of result etc
}
```

Note that this is more or less pseudo code based on an invalid Xml. 
That look like once you add a common root and remove the last closing meta at the end...:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="row")]
public class Row {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="value")]
    public List<string> Value { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="data")]
public class Data {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="row")]
    public List<Row> Row { get; set; }
}
```

If you trust the properties order you can simply

```
Data.Row.Select(x => new GroupDto{
                Date = x.Value[0],
                Hour = x.Value[1],
                Group = x.Value[2],
                Status = x.Value[3],
            } )
```